# trying to input text file into 2d char array, however i get error "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string"?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader, filenotfoundexception, ioexception

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.*;

class SillyMaze{
    static char mazeArr[][];

    public static void main(String[] args){
        File mazeFile = new File("maze0.txt");
        String line;
        int row = 0;

        try{
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(mazeFile);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            mazeArr = new char[Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine())][Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine())];
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                mazeArr[row] = line.toCharArray();
                row++;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.err.println("FileNotFound: " + e.getMessage()); 
        }
        catch (IOException e){ 
                System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage()); 
        } 
    }
}
```

I'm trying to input text file "maze0.txt"

```
S#####
.....#
#.####
#.####
...#.G
##...#
```

but my terminal keeps saying

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "S#####"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)

I know i'm on the right path, but what corrections do i need to make? I'm having difficult trying to understand how to import this text file.

Comment: Well that String is obviously NOT an Integer. An Integer is something like "12345". Why are you using Integer.parseInt()?

Comment: @camickr silly me, i was trying to use parseInt to get the dimensions for the array